# LookupError: No installed app with label 'core'

Tags: django

Inicialmente o projeto usava django 1.7 mas estou migrando ele para django 1.10.3, mas quando tento usar o migrate informa esse erro  de que o 'core' não esta instalado, infelizmente não existe um aplicativo core no meu programa ! a unica coisa com esse nome e uma pasta com alguns aplicativos dentro, e eu simplesmente colocava o caminho deles, mas acho que isso não e aceito em django 1.10.3, qual seria o novo método de fazer isso ? ou me livrar desse erro ?

Edit: Erro

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 148, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'core'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 16, in check_user_model
    cls = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 195, in get_model
    return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'core'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa consultar a documentacao da versao 1.10 tem migrate (acredito que nao;. se for o caso tente utilizar o SOUTH e veja se ele é compativel com a versao 1.10.

Caso nada disso de certo voce vai ter que fazer do jeito antigo (Django antes do South/Migrate) a migracao do banco.

Comment: O problema não esta no migrate e sim no fato que alguma coisa mudou no django 1.10  e essa coisa tem alguma ligação com o core do próprio django, pois não existe nenhum app meu chamado core

Comment: Cola o erro aqui pra gente ve

Comment: Pergunta editada com a saída gerada

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema, e basicamente foi um erro meu nas configurações do projeto onde estava tentando acessar um user criado por mim com um caminho diferente, mas obrigado mesmo por ter tentado ajudar